# checked exceptions

Tags: java

I have been revising for a java exam. I'm not sure how to answer the following question about checked exceptions. Any help is appreciated. Cheers

InvalidMemberIdException is a checked exception class. It has two
constructors: one that takes no parameters and the other that takes a single String
parameter that is used as the message associated with the exception when it is
thrown.
Write the full definition of the InvalidMemberIdException class.

Answer (score 6):

something like:

```
public class InvalidMemberIdException extends Exception {    
    InvalidMemberIdException(){
       super();
    }

    InvalidMemberIdException(String message){
       super(message);
    }

}
```

the key thing to note is that according to

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Exception already has a message field, so I am just creating a new exception type that hooks into the Exception class's message field.  Also, note that Exception is a checked exception, so so is this new exception type.

Answer (score 3):

Your class should extend from the `Exception` class. It should contain two constructors, one without parameters, second with one `String` parameter. Both constructors should call corresponding constructors from the superclass.

Comment: +1 for not providing the entire solution. I would add the explanation that checked exceptions do not necessarily have to extend `java.lang.Exception` directly. They can also extend any class which itself extends `java.lang.Exception` (directly or indirectly), but it **cannot** extend `java.lang.RuntimeException` (directly or indirectly).